# how to change a pane to the main pane in tmux

Tags: linux, tmux

In tmux, when i use main-vertical layout, it always selects the main pane that will be having the larger size. Is there any way we can make the current pane the larger size when using main-vertical? or changing the current pane to the main pane.?

Answer (score 5):

Try the `rotate-window` command, bound to <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd> / <kbd>Meta-o</kbd> by default, or the `swap-pane` command, bound to <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd> (the two choices operate in opposite directions).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl + b</kbd>  + <kbd>space</kbd> rotates them and gives you some size options (limited). From the help listing:

<kbd>Ctrl + b</kbd>  +

- <kbd>Meta + up</kbd>  resize-pane -U 5
- <kbd>Meta + down</kbd>  resize-pane -D 5
- <kbd>Meta + left</kbd>  resize-pane -L 5
- <kbd>Meta + right</kbd>  resize-pane -R 5
- <kbd>Ctrl + up</kbd>  resize-pane -U
- <kbd>Ctrl + down</kbd>  resize-pane -D
- <kbd>Ctrl + left</kbd>  resize-pane -L
- <kbd>Ctrl + right</kbd>  resize-pane -R

Comment: Space is for switching layout, not rotating windows.  The OP has already chosen a layout (`main-vertical`).

Comment: On mine it also does a 2/3 1/3 split as an option also, which I thought may be a quicker solution than resizing specifically

Comment: I think the OP is happy with the split ratios, just not which pane went into which side of the split.

Comment: yeah.. not happy about which pane became the bigger one